# \texorpdfstring for a full book

Tags: math-mode, hyperref

I am currently writing a thesis which is full of math equations and I always get the warning

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
```

I have read that the solution is by using `\texorpdfstring` for each section, however, I was wondering if it could be possible to use one command for the whole document which will definitely improve the readability of the `.tex` file.

Comment: it is only important for the bookmarks. If you do not really need it then igore it.

Comment: Did the mentioned solution work for you? If yes, we can introduce some "for every section: \texorpdfstring"-magic, I guess. But for that, you have to post an example as minimal as possible which results in this warning.

Comment: I think you can use `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands` to add code that disable commands when generating the bookmark.

Comment: where should this "\pdfstringdefDisableCommands" be added?

Answer (score 7):

Since you mentioned equations, here's a MWE containing some:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A Sample Chapter \ensuremath{\sin a+\cos b=c}}

\chapter{Another Sample Chapter $\sin a + \cos b = c$}

\end{document}
```

This produces a load of warnings such as:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\mathop' on input line 9.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\mathgroup' on input line 9.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\symoperators' on input line 9.
```

In each case the warning identifies the problematic token. You can use `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands` to disable these tokens while the bookmarks are being created.

In the MWE, the first heading uses `\ensuremath` (which isn't recommended, but this is for illustrative purposes). This can be disabled so that it ignores its argument like this:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\ensuremath\@gobble}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A Sample Chapter \ensuremath{\sin a+\cos b=c}}

\chapter{Another Sample Chapter $\sin a + \cos b = c$}

\end{document}
```

This now suppresses the warnings for the first `\chapter` (but not the second) and the equation is discarded from the bookmark. You can use a similar method for other problematic commands. You can use `\@gobble` in the `\let` assignment to discard the argument (as in the above) or `\@firstofone` to discard the command and just put the argument in the bookmark or `\@empty` to discard a command that doesn't have an argument.

The second `\chapter` is a bit more problematic. Do you want to completely discard the equation (as in the first case with `\ensuremath` above) or do you want to try to approximate the equation in the bookmark? The following will make `\sin` and `\cos` just display `sin` and `cos` but you'll still get a warning about the math shift:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
 \let\ensuremath\@gobble
 \def\sin{sin }%
 \def\cos{cos }%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A Sample Chapter \ensuremath{\sin a+\cos b=c}}

\chapter{Another Sample Chapter $\sin a + \cos b = c$}

\end{document}
```

This just leaves the warnings:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 17.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 17.
```

However, you do at least get a slightly more intelligible set of bookmarks as shown below:

[image: Image of bookmarks and table of contents]